# iScroll 4 not working properly

Tags: android, cordova, iscroll

I have downloaded iScroll.js and used in one of my phonegap project i.e.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myScroll;
function loaded() {
myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
</script>
```

It doesn't work on normal browsers too but **when i inspect elements it started working absolutely fine??** don't know what the problem is...

Comment: Scumbag Nishant Mahajan, add a question with more than a thousand viewed. Say that the only answer _doesn't work_ before saying _i had solved the problem now..._ with no further informations :P

Comment: Sorry Scumbag, i forgot to share the solution but i'll definitely do that soon.

Comment: Thanks Nishant Mahakan :)

Answer (score 2):

**How to use iScroll**
1) Need to prevent the default behavior of standard touch events. Easy to do this, by adding **preventDefault()** in your touchmove event.

2) Initialize the *iScroll* object on DOMContentLoaded or on window load.

Change your code to,

```
    function loaded() {
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', loaded, false);
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: and by the way, it perfectly running when i inspect elements in any browser.

Comment: If you feel like sharing, can I see your code(Both html and css)

Answer (score 2):

don't define the height and width to inner div where content exists. and create object iScroll after content is dynamically rendered completely.